# Minimum Hard Drive Size for SharePoint 2010 and SQL Server 2008 dev machine

Tags: sharepoint

I plan to have VS 2010 on my local box, and I'm building a VM with SP 2010 and SQL Server 2008. What hard drive size should I shoot for on the VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much data are you planning to store in the database?

Windows Server is going to use up a fair chunk in the multi-gigabyte range, and then the installers for the rest are around 2 to 3GB, plus whatever data you need.

So I'd go with at least 40GB, up to 60GB.

Comment: my data will be minimal, and do not factor in the OS, then how much would u say, and how much more if I wanted to install Visual Studio 2010 as well?

Comment: 40GB-60GB is good.  A Win2k8 install is around 20GB just by itself.

Comment: @user8160 - see Holo's answer re Windows. Visual Studio 2010 looks for around 5GB including help files, maybe more.